# Is there a limit on the table or database creation for CockroachDB Serverless

Tags: cockroachdb

We know that CockroachDB Serverless provides auto-scaling for tenant, but is there a limit on the number of tables or databases that each tenant is allowed to create?

Seems that the doc didn't explicitly mentioned this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So CockroachDB doesn't impose a hard limit on the tables or databases that a tenant is allowed to create, but there is a limit on the [span](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/show-ranges#:%7E:text=CockroachDB%20stores%20all%20user%20data,an%20interval%20within%20this%20keyspace.)-per-tenant, which implicitly impose a restriction on the number of tables / database.